# How can I add one more table to this hive command?

Tags: hive

```
dt1=$1
  
desfile="data_$dt1"
 hql="
 select DISTINCT b.mid, b.create_time, d.content from
     (select mid, create_time, to_id, dt from table_1 where dt>=$dt1 and to_id='1042015' ) b
  join
      (select mid, content from table_2 where dt>=$dt1) d
  on(b.mid=d.mid)
 "
  
 hive -e "$hql"> $desfile
```

This query is to get content from two tables table_1 and table_2, different fields from different tables. If I want to get one more field from another table table_3 conditioned on the same 'mid' field, should I change the query to this form below:

```
hql="
     select DISTINCT a.off_time, b.mid, b.create_time, d.content from
         (select mid, create_time, to_id, dt from table_1 where dt>=$dt1 and to_id='1042015' ) b
      join
          (select mid, content from table_2 where dt>=$dt1) d
      join 
          (select mid, off_time from table_3 where dt>=dt1) a
      on(b.mid=d.mid=a.mid)
     "
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't join on all three tables at the same time, but you should join b and d first, and then join to a.

```
select DISTINCT a.off_time, b.mid, b.create_time, d.content from
         (select mid, create_time, to_id, dt from table_1 where dt>=$dt1 and to_id='1042015') b
      join
          (select mid, content from table_2 where dt>=$dt1) d
      on(b.mid = d.mid)
      join 
          (select mid, off_time from table_3 where dt>=$dt1) a
      on(b.mid = a.mid)
```